# Select all that has exact fields

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: **flows**, **document_types** and **documents**. Flows has many documents that belongs to document type.

Let's say I need to select all flows that has documents that belongs to a certain list of document types, for example, where document type id in 1, 2, 3 and 4. In other words, I want to select only flows that has documents with ALL of above document type id. How logic/query should I use?

My first try was with `where in` but it doesn't ensures that the documents has exactly all document types, it queries for at least one:

```
select * from flows where id in (
    select flow_id from documents where document_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
);
```

I have to write my queries with Laravel Eloquent but this will be trivial after discovering the correct logic.

Comment: You can use GROUP BY in combination with conditional sum something like this `GROUP BY <column> HAVING SUM(document_type_id = 1) = 1 AND SUM(document_type_id = 2) = 1 ....`

Comment: Because of a comment directed to me on Gordon Linoff answer "@RaymondNijland so should I group by "document_type_id" before?" read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem" or "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 6):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select f.*
from flows f
where f.id in (select d.flow_id
               from documents d
               where d.document_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
               group by d.flow_id
               having count(distinct d.document_type) = 4
              );
```

The `= 4` guarantees that all four types are found in `documents`.  Note that I've also added table aliases and qualified all column references.  These are good ideas for any queries you write.

You can also do this with a correlated subquery, which may be more efficient in MySQL:

```
select f.*
from flows f
where exists (select 1
              from documents d
              where d.document_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) and
                    d.flow_id = f.id
              having count(distinct d.document_type) = 4
             );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `documents(flow_id, document_type)`.

Comment: Do i mis a `GROUP BY` here? I know most databases work fine using `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` i always find i wierd to read and find it a "hack"

Comment: @RaymondNijland so should I group by "document_type_id" before?

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Not at all ;)  Look carefully now.  (Thank you).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), you can get `DISTINCT` **document_type_id(s)**, for a **flow id**, concatenated in a comma separated string. Use `HAVING` clause to filter out afterwards.

Here is a sample query (Please edit the table and column name(s) accordingly):

```
SELECT f.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.document_type_id 
                    ORDER BY d.document_type_id ASC) AS document_types_in_flow 
FROM flows AS f 
INNER JOIN documents AS d ON d.flow_id = f.id 
GROUP BY f.id 
HAVING document_types_in_flow = '1,2,3,4'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add that constraint using the built-in relations...

```
$flows = Flow::has('documents', '=', 4)->get();
```

This will depend on your relations being properly setup and probably a unique key in your database which would not allow a specific flow to have more than 1 document attached in your pivot table.

It might also be smart to make that 4 dynamic by counting number of documents first and dropping that count variable into the query rather than 4.

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_has

A more personalized solution...

```
$documentIds = [1,2,3,4];

$flows = Flow::whereHas('documents', function($q) use ($documentIds) {
    $q->whereIn('document_type_id', $documentIds);
}, '=', count($documentIds));
```

Comment: It means it's only going to return flows that have 4 documents attached.  I've linked to the API which describes this method.

Comment: Ok, let me see how this can help me. Maybe `Flow::whereHas('documents', function () { ... })->has('documents', '=', 4)->get()`

Comment: `whereHas` also takes additional parameters for this same exact thing `Flow::whereHas('documents', function () { ... }, '=', 4)`.  No need to use `has`